# How to handle Powerpoint chart from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a PowerPoint file and a chart in the second slide.
I am not able to set height and width of the chart while writing macro in an Excel file. Below is the code I am trying. Please note I need to modify height and width only from Excel macro.

```
Sub controlPPT()
    Dim PPT As Object
    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")     
    With Application.FileDialog(1)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "PPT files", "*.pptx"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Set slideTwo = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
            slideTwo.Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea.Height = 120
            slideTwo.Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea.Width = 200
            slideTwo.Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea.Left = 0
            slideTwo.Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea.Top = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `Application.FileDialog` doesn't open selected file, you should open it explicitly:

```
Sub controlPPT()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pres As Object
    Dim slideTwo As Object

    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    With Application.FileDialog(1)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "PPT files", "*.pptx"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Set pres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
            Set slideTwo = pres.Slides(2)
            slideTwo.Select
            With slideTwo.Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea
                .Height = 120
                .Width = 200
                .Left = 0
                .Top = 0
            End With
        End If
    End With

    'save/close presentation
    pres.Save
    pres.Close
    'clean up
    Set pres = Nothing
    pptApp.Quit
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

also for reliability I would change `slideTwo.Shapes(1)` to `slideTwo.Shapes("Chart1")` where "Chart1" should be replaced with actual chart name.

Comment: My code is able to open the ppt file, I am able to do all kind of changes in ppt but the ones mentioned above

Comment: Your code takes _currently active_ presentation `Set slideTwo = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2)` (which is already opened), but not the one you selected using `FileDialog`. Btw, have you tried to run my code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am opening the file using the below code
PPT.Presentations.Open .SelectedItems(1)

Comment: ok, it's no problem, also before modifying chart, you should lect lide where it placed: `slideTwo.Select` (see my code)

Comment: You are great, I have been trying to find out solution since yesterday....slideTwo.Select works just fine. Thanks a lot, you have been very helpful.